# Is it possible to maximize profit in dog betting?

Tags: probability, optimization

I was wondering what's the math behind maximizing profits in dog betting? Is it even possible? Imagine there were six dogs with the following returns. E.g. Dog1 returns 9 times what you bet on it. If I was allowed to bet on each dog any amount of money, it doesn't have to be consistent (e.g. 1 dollar on Dog 1, 2 dollars on Dog 2), then how much would it be for me to have a guaranteed **profit**?

Or what's the math behind it so I know that it's not possible.

Dog1 = 9x

Dog2 = 7x

Dog3 = 4.5x

Dog4 = 2.5x

Dog5 = 6x

Dog6 = 7x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the current form that you have it (with multiples greater than one on the returns of each dog), any nonzero amount that you bet on the dogs would return a profit. In addition, as it stands, you have not made clear exactly what it is you want to maximize. Do you want to maximize profits while minimizing the amount that you have to bet? Or are you willing to bet any amount if it maximizes profit? If so, with the numbers you've written down, there is no minimum amount that maximizes profit. The profit function is monotonically increasing, always.

In general, what you're looking for is maximizing the expected value of the return on betting on dogs. However, for this expected value to have a maximum, you need to be losing money on some dogs, and winning on others with some probability. Let me know if you have different numbers we can work with.

Comment: I am willing to bet any amount as long as it maximizes profit. What do you mean by monotonically increasing? What if I was willing to lose on 1 out of 6 dogs, or 2 out of 6 dogs? Would this make any difference in the calculations?
.
An easier one would be Dog1 returns 2x and Dog2 returns 11x. I know some numbers that solve the problem but I want to know the math behind it. 
.
Thanks!